# Работа с командной строкой  в WPF

Tags: wpf, .net, c#

Сейчас в моем проекте доступ к аргументам командной строки организован так:

```
Application.Current.Properties["value"].ToString())
```

Я считаю, что если хранить аргументы в статическом объекте, то доступ можно упростить, и он будет выглядеть так:

```
MyProgramm.App.value
```

Меня интересует, как правильнее решить эту задачу?

Answer (score 1):

Я обычно делаю следующим образом.

1. Определяю класс `Options`, который содержит типизированные свойства, соответствующие смыслу параметров командной строки.
2. В конструкторе разбираю командную строку, и присваиваю значения нужным свойствам.
3. Для упрощения кода нужность/ненужность свойства и его возможное значение по умолчанию прописываю в кастомном атрибуте.
4. Код, управляющий разбором командной строки и интерпретацией атрибутов, вынесен в абстрактный базовый класс для повторного использования. Доступ к атрибутам ведётся через reflection (поскольку разбор командной строки ведётся один раз за работу приложения, расходы на reflection можно считать незначительными).

Таким образом сочетается лёгкая расширяемость с преимуществами жёсткой типизации.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, лучше оставить словарь (расширяемость). Для упрощения работы с длинными именами рекомендую использовать псевдонимы. В данном случае, лучше использовать перечисление, т.е создается перечисление или класс со статическими полями, которые являются идентификаторами в словаре. После этого код может выглядеть так:

```
// Обращение к словарю
Application.Current.Properties{CmdLineKeys.Value].ToString())
```

Если поле `Application.Current.Properties` часто используется в одном контексте, стоит задуматься о локальной переменной.